# Lifespan of Node `fs.mkdtemp()` directories

Tags: node.js, fs

This feels like something that should be easily googlable (or even better, be [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdtemp_prefix_options_callback)), but I can't seem to find anything which explains just how temporary the "temporary" directories made by Node's `fs.mkdtemp()` are.

In terms of cleaning up after myself, I know that I can manually delete the directory when I'm done with it, but that negates the point of it being temporary. On the flip side, if I want to include the directory's path (as a string, not a pointer) in a callback function, can I count on the directory remaining in existence as long as the node process is still running?

[Note: I know that to a certain extent this is a moot point because I can work inside of `/tmp` (or whatever `os.tempdir()` returns) and the OS will eventually do the cleanup work for me (but not so eagerly as to make passing the path within a single node process a dangerous thing). But I'd still kind of like to know about `mkdtemp()`, if anyone has the answer readily at hand.]

Comment: I'm going to throw in an educated guess here. Since this is designed to work on many different OS, it will be up to each OS how it deals with temporary directories. Since it's not possible to give any guarantees, none are given. This is what's usually refered to as implementation defined.

Comment: @super - If what you're saying is true, it sounds like Node doesn't do the cleanup, leaving it to the OS to get rid of the directory. But if that's the case, and you call `mkdtemp()` somewhere else _besides_ `/tmp`, how will the OS know to (eventually) delete the directory?

Comment: What makes you think you can choose where the directory is created?

Comment: The Node docs. :-) Check out the link in my original question. If I do `fs.mkdtempSync(path.join(process.env.HOME, "myTempDir-"))`, for example, I'll end up with a folder at `~/myTempDir-xxxxxx` (where `xxxxxx` is some six-digit hex number in lowercase).

Comment: Ah, right. Since they used prefix as the parameter name is seemed to indicate that it was not also possible to supply a path as a prefix. In that case there's nothing inherently temporary about the directory created, more then the randomly generated suffix.